# How to execute a task as root without helper tool in objective C in OS X?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, cocoa

I have a small command line application that I've written in C which opens a `tun` virtual network device. It requires root in order to do this.

I now want to build a GUI for this app, which will allow you to select the `tun` device (e.x. `tun0`) and also will run `ifconfig` to assign it an IP address and netmask. I'd also like to have the command line tool be able to be killed from the GUI.

I've built the GUI itself (buttons, etc), but I'm not sure how to execute my command line app with root privileges. I've managed to figure out that it has something to do with Authorization Services, but I'm not sure where to go from here. The examples I've seen don't let you kill the process you've started. From what I can tell if the application can hold on to the authorization it got at the beginning, it might be able to continue to execute commands (the`ipconfig` for example, or killing the process with `kill` or `killall`). I haven't been able to find much documentation on this kind of stuff. I've read the apple docs, but those kinda created more questions than provided answers.

Comment: Too little for an answer, but you **could** write a second little app in C that only takes commands from your GUI (e.g. via pipe) and is installed [`suid root`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#SUID).

Comment: Did you read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AuthenticationAndAuthorizationGuide/Authorization/Authorization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011200-CH3-SW1

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad yes, I've read the apple documentation already. Didn't really give me much clues. It seems to say that you can add the lock icon but it doesn't detail how to do that, and how to keep the authorization. It also looks like that will allow you to execute code that will require privilege from within your app, but not execute other tasks.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/03authtasks/authtasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000995-CH206-BCIGAIAG